# Print salted hash in shaow file Linux

Tags: python, linux, hash, shadow

I need help in printing the salted hash of shadow file in linux instead of just 'x', '*' or '!'. So far I have been able to print out other entries using panda:

```
def print_shadow_file(path):
    df = pd.read_csv(path, sep=':', header=None, usecols=[0,1,2,3], names=['username', 'salt', 'uid', 'gid'])
    print(df)

path = './shadow.txt'
print_shadow_file(path)
```

This does not print out the has it only prints 'x' or '*'. Is there a library that can achieve this? Also to detect the algorithm used.

Comment: Do the hashed passwords actually appear in that file?

Comment: No they dont. They appear as '*' '!' 'x'. My question is "Is there a function one can use to have them printed out?"

Answer (score 0):

I think you read passwd file instead of shadow file. Check it please.

password file contains entries like this:

> root:**x**:0:0:root:/root:/bin/bash

shadow file contains entries like this:

> root:**$salt$hash**:17530:0:99999:7:::

Comment: I read shadow file but the output are just '!' or '*' for the salt entries. I am asking if there is a way to print the **$salt$hash**  instead of '!' or '*' also to detect the hash algorithm.

Comment: You mean you cannot see **$salt$hash** string at any normal user like **root** user? "_!_" and "_*_" sign literally means there is no password set for that user. I guess this linux are using central or other authentication methods than password/shadow file combination.